# Android programming - Code optimization

Tags: android

I am a newcomer to the world of Android. Few days ago I tried to write a program whose purpose is to enable / disable bluetooth by following instruction in a book for beginner and succeeded. However its size is 888 kb, compared with one bluetooth enabler application that I found on the Internet, whose size was only 56kb. Was my code too complicated ? Which ways can I take to review my code for a smaller size ?

Comment: if you plan on releasing your application to the public make sure you look into obfuscating your code. Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off without seeing the code or even comparison of the two apps it's hard to make a comparison. However, some things that come to mind are

- Proguard
- Fewer/smaller icons and images (only 1 image for mdpi)
- Fewer layouts

But either way, I wouldn't be worrying much about 900kB. Most template apps generated by Android Studio will have some minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your Gradle file you have [minifyEnable](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking). 
If you have a ton of images in your app, you need to optimize them to the resource sizes.